# Add style to table by id

Tags: css

I have a table #good-table.
Could I add to all content in this table ( a,div,img,td,th ... ) something like

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

but only for this table and content in this table.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#good-table, #good-table * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

`#good-table *` will cover the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements, but if you want to select them explicitly you can use `#good-table::before`, `#good-table *::before`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but how to add ::before and ::after  here?

Comment: You shouldn't need it as they are covered by `#good-table *`. But the syntax would be `#good-table, #good-table *,#good-table::before, #good-table *::before,#good-table::after, #good-table *::after`